# Access current server application URL from provider in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs

To provide a little bit of context.

I am working with AWS SES, and for testing purposes in ephemeral environments, I need to configure the SES client pointing to an endpoint of my application. For this I need to build the absolute URL which will be something like `${myAppUrl}/_ses`.

I cannot handle this from env vars because I cannot know beforehand which will be the url of the ephemeral environment.

I have been trying injecting the HTTPAdapterHost which according to Nest docs should work since it allows me to get a reference to the in-context app instance, but for some reason this instance does not have the `getUrl` method defined.

```js
import { SESClient, SESClientConfig } from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { HttpAdapterHost } from '@nestjs/core';
import { usesLocalstack } from '@shared/errors/utils/helpers';

export const AWS_SES_CLIENT = Symbol('AWS_SES_CLIENT');

export const AWSSesClientProvider = {
  provide: AWS_SES_CLIENT,
  useFactory: async (
    config: ConfigService,
    httpAdapterHost: HttpAdapterHost,
  ) => {
    const credentials: SESClientConfig['credentials'] = {
      accessKeyId: config.get<string>('aws.accessKeyId'),
      secretAccessKey: config.get<string>('aws.secretAccessKey'),
    };

    const region: SESClientConfig['region'] = config.get<string>('aws.region');

    const isEphemeral = config.get<string>('environment') === 'ephemeral';

    const instance = httpAdapterHost.httpAdapter.getInstance();

    console.log({ myInstance: instance }); // I can see the instance object logged with a bunch of methods but not the getUrl one

    const endpoint: SESClientConfig['endpoint'] = isEphemeral
      ? await instance.getUrl() // getURl is not a function error
      : config.get<string>('aws.endpoint');

    const configObject: SESClientConfig = {
      region,
      ...(usesLocalstack() && { endpoint, credentials }),
    };

    return new SESClient(configObject);
  },
  inject: [ConfigService, HttpAdapterHost],
};
```

Comment: do you want to get the app url?

Comment: `instance` will be the underlying HTTP lib (like Express or Fastify, depending on which http adapter you're using). So I guess you should look for a solution to those libs

Comment: sid yes I want to get the app url.